# css animation doesn't display properly in edge

Tags: css, microsoft-edge

So I'm having some trouble with a css animation "underline from center" to be precise.
It displays properly in every browser except edge.
I'm getting small dots underneath the links where the animation displays itself (see picture)
[dots underneath links in navbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B63MF.png)
enter code here`

```
.hvr-underline-from-center {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px transparent;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.hvr-underline-from-center:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  left: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #b80c0c;
  height: 4px;
  -webkit-transition-property: left, right;
  transition-property: left, right;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.1s;
  transition-duration: 0.1s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}
.hvr-underline-from-center:hover:before, .hvr-underline-from-center:focus:before, .hvr-underline-from-center:active:before {
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

enter code here`

Thanks for the help

Comment: Post your CSS directly here, between code tags, not just as an external link.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: there it's done I rarely post questions on stackoverflow sorry

Comment: Seems to be working just fine for me: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zpLVoZ

Comment: yes but it doesn't work in edge it work everywhere else except edge :/

Comment: It works on edge, depending on the text (and maybe also the density of your screen). This type of thing also happens sometime on Firefox and chrome. It's a rounding error : that's why on your picture you've got dot below some menu items but not all. Try adding a visibility hidden, it'll do the trick. Also for this type of thing animating `transform: scaleX` if better performance wise than animating an item width, (and an item with a scaleX(0) will always have a length of 0 no rounding error can happen here).

Comment: there it works with with visibilty trick thanks for the tip man :D

Comment: @NicolasReynis can you put your answer in as an answer since it solved the OP issue. Thanks.

Comment: @gregwhitworth: Done

Answer (score 1):

This is not an Edge issue. It works on Edge, depending on the text (and maybe also the density of your screen). This type of thing also happens sometime on Firefox and even Chrome.

It's a rounding error : that's why on your picture you've got dot below some menu items but not all.

Try adding a visibility hidden, it'll do the trick.

Also for this type of thing animating transform: scaleX if better performance wise than animating an item width, (and an item with a scaleX(0) will always have a length of 0 no rounding error can happen here)